# Контент радио кнопки не убирается

Tags: html, css, javascript

Есть радиокнопка с подгружаемым контентом, всё работает за исключением одного - когда нажимаете Показать содержимое категории 1 и затем Показать содержимое категории 2, то содержимое категории 1 не убирается (не присваевается cat.style.display = "none";)
Подскажите как сделать, что бы после выбора др. категории  у не выбранных исчезало содержимое

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function showOrHide(cb, cat) {
    cb = document.getElementById(cb);
    cat = document.getElementById(cat);
    if (cb.checked) cat.style.display = "block";
    else cat.style.display = "none";
  } 
</script>

Выбирете тариф
<div>
  <input name="gender" type = 'radio' id = 'cb1' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb1", "cat1");'/>Показать содержимое категории 1
  <br />
  <div id = 'cat1' style = 'display: none;'><select id="srok-days">
                    <option selected="selected" value="10">10 дней</option>
                    <option value="20">20 дней</option>
                    <option value="30">30 дней</option>
                    <option value="31">1 месяц (31 дней)</option>
                    <option value="91">3 месяца (91 дней)</option>
                </select></div>
  <input name="gender" type = 'radio' id = 'cb2' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb2", "cat2");' />Показать содержимое категории 2
  <br />
  <div id = 'cat2' style = 'display: none;'><select id="srok-days">

                    <option value="365">1 год (365 дней)</option>
                    <option value="547">1,5 года (547 дней)</option>
                    <option value="735">2 года (735 дней)</option>
                    <option value="No limited">Неограничено</option>
                </select></div>
  <input name="gender" type = 'radio' id = 'cb3' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb3", "cat3");' />Показать содержимое категории 3
  <br />
  <div id = 'cat3' style = 'display: none;'>Содержимое категории 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно применить ко всем элементам `cat` какой-то общий класс, к примеру `cat-content`. По клику скрывать все элементы `cat-content` и в конце отображать необходимый блок. Это если не выходить из текущей разметки. А так Вы бы могли оставить лишь классы (убрать идентификаторы) и работать уже с ними.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно не самый крутой ответ и правильный, НО рабочий http://jsfiddle.net/6RfCL/

```js
var inp = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
 for(i=0; i<inp.length; i++){
  inp[i].onclick = fun;
 }
 function fun(event){
  var allDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.need');
  for(j=0; j<allDiv.length; j++){
   allDiv[j].style.display = 'none';
  }
  s = event.target.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display = 'block';

 }
```

```html
<body>
 
Выбирете тариф
<div>
  <input name="gender" type = 'radio' id = 'cb1'/>Показать содержимое категории 1
  <br />
  <div id = 'cat1' style = 'display: none;' class="need"><select id="srok-days">
                    <option selected="selected" value="10">10 дней</option>
                    <option value="20">20 дней</option>
                    <option value="30">30 дней</option>
                    <option value="31">1 месяц (31 дней)</option>
                    <option value="91">3 месяца (91 дней)</option>
                </select></div>
  <input name="gender" type = 'radio' id = 'cb2'/>Показать содержимое категории 2
  <br />
  <div id = 'cat2' style = 'display: none;' class="need"><select id="srok-days">

                    <option value="365">1 год (365 дней)</option>
                    <option value="547">1,5 года (547 дней)</option>
                    <option value="735">2 года (735 дней)</option>
                    <option value="No limited">Неограничено</option>
                </select></div>
  <input name="gender" type = 'radio' id = 'cb3'/>Показать содержимое категории 3
  <br />
  <div id = 'cat3' style = 'display: none;' class="need">Содержимое категории 3</div>
</div>

</body>
```

скрипт в конец html, в скрипте много nextSibling т.к. есть различный текст и теги типо br по этому перебор элементов вызвал такое количество, а вообще проще через JQ toggle, надеюсь помог Вам